# How to model highly relational data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, nosql, data-modeling, graph-databases

I have a problem with data modeling in MongoDB. Documentation doesn't seem to propose solutions that would work in my case.

My particular use case is very similar to the Facebook friends system. **I have a collection of
users and each user can connect with other users by sending invitations that are either accepted or rejected.** This mechanism will be foundational for other features like calculating mutual friends, recommending the most adequate friends etc.

Seemingly **popular solutions would be**:

- Embedding ids of friends in the user document as an array
- Embedding friends data in the user document as an array

But **that's problematic - if someone has few thousands of friends then performance will suffer** and performance is important for me.

My idea was to create separate collection where every document would be a connection between two users. That document could have embedded data of each user and adequate additional data, for example status of connection invitation. What do you think of this design?

Also, **are there any battle tested methods of handling such situations in MongoDB** when performance is crucial? I'm also open to other dbs suggestions, I was thinking about graph dbs.

Answer (score 0):

This use case would be easy to handle in a graph DB like [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/).

For example, you could use neo4j's Cypher language to store the fact that user 123 created an invitation and sent it to a number of users this way:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 123})
CREATE (u)-[:CREATED]->(i:Invitation {id: 999, text: '...', date: ..., location: ...})
UNWIND [234, 345, 456] AS inviteeId
MATCH (u1:User {id: inviteeId})
CREATE (i)-[:INVITED]->(u1)
```

And whenever a user responds, you can store it like this:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 345}), (i:Invitation {id: 999})
CREATE (u)-[:RESPONDED {accept: false}]->(i)
```

Finally, to see the distinct users who accepted any of user 123's invitations:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 123})-[:CREATED]->(:Invitation)<-[:RESPONDED {accept: true}]-(acceptor:User)
RETURN DISTINCT acceptor
```